# PDFBox: parsing files with tables

Tags: java, parsing, pdf, pdfbox

I need to parse a 4 pages file that contains train timetables.

[image: example]

The PDFBox problem: empty table cell = deleted!! :-(

Is it any way to make PDBBox assume that empty table cell = one special char/sequence?

Let's take an example:

-> station "Thann (A)"

-> I want to keep only the times if "Thann(D)" not empty... so I wouldn't keep 07.01!

-> how could I do this?

For now my app is working, I read the 4 pages of the PDF, and analyze the buffer data with a custom java class to get the data I need.

(I do it this way because with Android, there is a memory crash when I read the PDF twice or more... despite the fact that it works well with a standard java project!)

But this way, there are few times that I don't need to get because the next station is empty.

I would like to get for "Thann (A)":

06.01|06.30|06.21|07.01|**(empty)**|07.30

06.02|06.32|06.22|**(empty)**|07.03|07.33

***AND NOT:***

06.01|06.30|06.21|07.01|07.30

06.02|06.32|06.22|07.03|07.33

Comment: How do you currently go about parsing? That is, what methods do you use for reading specific cells and how do you use them and their return values to obtain your negative example?

Comment: [*This answer*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28370692/1729265) may be helpful. It extends the PDFBox `PDFTextStripper` to return text lines which attempt to reflect the PDF file layout, adding space characters to represent gaps like your empty cells. You may have to find your own optimum `fixedCharWidth` value...

Comment: Jan: I read the whole file (String Text = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);), no specific cells treatment

Comment: Mkl: ok, will have a look, thanks ;-)

Comment: Ok, it works well, I have my empty columns in my String buffer, thanks!

BUT, now, how make the difference between space char=empty column and space char=real space char, within the String buffer?

In the class LayoutTextStripper, couldn't I replace the  space char=empty column with a special char/sequence, for instance, "ß"=empty column? 

Where to do it?

Comment: @mkl Your link is dead

Comment: @beldaz Yes, the OP of that question had deleted his question and my answer with it. But I've meanwhile copied the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45842515/1729265).

Comment: Thanks @mkl - Really annoying when a good answer gets nuked by OP deleting a question.